# Determining how many fixed size child objects can be contained in a variable width parent

Tags: html, size, parent

I think this is quite a simple one, but I'm stumped. I am developing a page which has a bad running along the bottom of the page. On the left is a left arrow and on the right a right arrow. The space in-between will be filled with thumbnails.

I'm trying to work out the best way of filling the space with the thumbnails, ideally I don't want any 'white space', but I also don't want any overlapping. I'm wondering if I should use javascript to determine the pixel size of the div, then use a while-loop in javascript. Is there an easier option do you think?

Many thanks in advance

I have a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/149/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    right
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <div id="child">
      child
      </div>
      <div id="child">
      child 2
      </div>
      <div id="child">
      child 3
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float:left;
    width:67px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
#middle {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width:67px;
    background-color:#ff5500;
}
#child{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#ff5500;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;

}
```

Comment: is this your are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/164/

Comment: Thanks Era, that's close, I think ultimately I'm looking to only display enough child objects in the parent so that there is no overlapping. Almost like "determine width of parent, divide this by fixed width of child, remove decimal places, display number of child divs multiplied by this number." I'm overcomplicating I am sure!

Comment: i got everything except "display number of child divs multiplied by this number." can you elaborate this?

Comment: what I am trying to work out is a way of finding the maximum number of fixed size 'child' divs that can be accommodated in a parent, and ONLY displaying that amount..... So for EG if the parent div is 320 px and each child div is 100 px then the answer is 3. I don't want the child divs to overlap on the right hand side. Using my crude 'sum' on this example.... parent width (300) divide by child width (100) = 3.2 remove decimal places = 3. Use this result to display only 3 divs. - thank you